# How to use a method inside ElectronJS's main process, when the method receives a path to import a local file?

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron

I am developing an Electron app, and I need to use a NodeJS library in the main process.

The library is called `node-libxml`. I must use it to validate an XML string against a given DTD.

The method that loads the DTD in memory (for posterior validation) is `loadDtds()`, and it receives an array of strings as parameter. The strings are paths to the files containing the DTDs.

But, since this method is called inside the main process of Electron, it does not recognize the given path as a valid parameter.

The function called later to validate the XML against the DTDs in memory returns null, which according to the docs, is expected when it does not find any dtd file in the given URL's.

How can I write this method in a way that it finds the local DTD files and loads them into memory from the main process of ElectronJS?

I built the Electron app with `npm create @quick-start/electron`

I tried writing the method like it says in the documentation:

main.js:

`loadDtds('./spec.dtd')`

But after calling the method for validation `.validateAgainstDtds()` it returned null, which according to the docs, happens when there are no dtds loaded in memory.

The expected result was to have the DTD file locally opened, loaded into memory, and used by the validateAgainstDtds() method

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to at least include a [mcve].

Comment: You would probably be better off using absolute file paths instead of relative file paths. Additionally,  even if relative file paths did work during development,  they probably wouldn't work during production. Add the code you have so far for this functionality to you question to improve the chances of someone providing an answer.